# listOfArticles() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print models attribute value in template, but I am getting "listOfArticles() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" error

**views.py**

```
def articles(request):
    model = News.objects.order_by('-date')[: 5]
    context = {
        'models': model
    }
    return render(request, 'articles.html', context)

def listOfArticles(request):
    models = News.objects.order_by('-date')[: 1]
    context = {
        'models': models
    }
    return render(request, 'articlesDetail.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r '^$', 'articles.views.articles', name = "latest_articles"),
    url(r '^(\d+)$', 'articles.views.listOfArticles'),

)
```

**models.py**

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length = 256)
    author_Detail = models.CharField("Author", max_length = 128)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Published Date")


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "News"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Yes I invoked http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/3

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `url(r '^(\d+)$', 'articles.views.listOfArticles'),` expects that a integer is there in url `(\d+)`. Change your url pattern to something relevent and you'll be good to proceed. You can do something like `r'^articles-list/$` :)

Comment: If user click the link then I want to open the details of assocaiated link wrt primary key of the articles

Comment: In that case replace `def listOfArticles(request)` with `def listOfArticles(request, article_id)` and `(\d+)` with `(?P<article_id>\d+)`

Comment: Please ask a new question for the same. Just for info please refer to django include tag.